# Could not load scene into memory. Your document may be damaged

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

today I opened my flash project in CS6 and after it opened in the output I receive this message: "Could not load scene into memory. Your document may be damaged." The only problem I saw was the flash component (textInput, and button) that I use for my project. They was transformed smaller and I can select them. :-o And the problem is that  try to open the previous version of the project and I found the same error. I think the only problem is FLASH COMPONENT. How can I make everything like it was (flash component). Is something about library ?I saw in library the TextInput are appear like symbol of component (3cubes).
  Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't work in some fast way so I had to change all my flash components in the library. After I changed,  the new components was looked also strange. But I didn't receive that error again and I can go ahead with my project now. Thank you anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes / solutions:

- Your `.fla` was originally authored on a computer with a different operating system. Try opening it on the computer it was created.
- Your `.fla` might have been made with a different version of Flash. Make sure you are opening it in the same version of Flash.
- Your `.fla` might have been corrupted. If you look in the folder and it says the file size is something like `7kb`, then your .fla file is seriously corrupted. Hopefully you have backups if this is the case.

Comment: thank you for response. Unfortunately I think it's not anyone of your options.. I would like to show you the project trough teamviewer if you want. can you? thanks